# Count read/write requests per day for the Azure Storage account in JAVA

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to count a number of read/write requests per day for my Azure Storage account or let's say for every object stored there. I know, that it could and even should be done directly in Azure Portal, but I need to receive this number on the client side. I use JAVA library for that. I have now the following code:

```
    public String getNumberOfRequests(String connectionString, Date startTime, Date endTime)  {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
            CloudAnalyticsClient client = account.createCloudAnalyticsClient();
            Iterable<LogRecord> records = client.listLogRecords(StorageService.BLOB, startDate, endDate, new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext());
            // ???
            return numberOfReadWriteRequests;
        } catch(...) {}
    }
```

How can I come from the beginning to this `numberOfReadWriteRequests`? Maybe instead of `LogRecord` objects I shoud rather work with `getHourMetricsTable` method and `CloudTable` objects? I can use only `CloudStorageAccount` and only JAVA-Api for that.

Comment: What do you mean readwrite request?

Comment: @JimXu I mean I have a Rest API in Java, which makes read/write requests to files, which are stored there. But if it will be only this API, that would make no problem, because there is Spring-actuator, which registers every http-request. The problem is, that users may generate SAS-tokens for read/write operations on files and I cannot get them through the API level, that's why I need a storage metric for that and I need to have this metrics in my Java-code for the further usage